# How to execute methods inherited from super-class in the subclass context?

Tags: java, inheritance, scope

I'm implementing a JPA-like process: all classes representing a table must subclass a `DBTable` abstract class which contains a HashMap linking column names (String) to `java.lang.reflect.Field` I got from calling `getClass().getDeclaredFields()` in the super-class constructor, called from the sub-class constructor.
This is working (I get the members I want from the sub-class).

I want to dynamically set these members of the subclass from a `ResultSet` which would call the `Field.set(this, ResultSet.getXXX(column))` in a method originally implemented in the super-class as a helper, but I get a `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class DBTable can not access a member of class MyTable with modifiers "protected"`.

So it turns out the method is executed in the super-class context (the abstract class!): if I copy/paste the method in my sub-class it's working fine.

Here is a snippet:

```
public abstract class DBTable {
    public DBTable() {
        hm = new HashMap<String,Field>();
        for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            hm.put(f.getAnnotation(Annot.class).value(), f); // 'annot' gives the column name
        }
    }

    protected boolean setFieldClass(Field f, ResultSet rs, int iCol) {
        Class<?> type = f.getType();
        if (type == String.class) {
            f.set(this, rs.getString(iCol)); // IllegalAccessException
        }
    }

    public boolean read(ResultSet rs) {
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 1; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            Field f = hm.get(meta.getColumnName(i));
            setFieldClass(f, rs, i); // IllegalAccessException
        }
    }

    public abstract someAbstractOtherMethod();
}

public class MyTable extends DBTable {

    @Annot("DataCol") // Set the column name to "DataCol"
    protected String dataStr;

    public MyTable() {
        super();
    }

    // 'dataStr' getter/setter
    // 'someAbstractOtherMethod' implementation
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyTable mt = new MyTable();
    ResultSet rs = ...; // Execute SELECT query returning a single row with a "DataCol" column containing a varchar(32)
    mt.read(rs); // IllegalAccessException
}
```

The `read` method called on a `MyTable` object is inherited from the `DBTable` class which, in turns, calls the `setFieldClass` method which throws the error.
If I copy/paste the `setFieldClass` method from `DBTable` to `MyTable` it works, as well as changing the `dataStr` member to public.

I could call a setter instead of directly setting the member value, but would like to avoid doing that (I'm not sure sub-classes will implement it nor will they all give the same names).

Thank you for sharing your insights with me! :)

Comment: In fact the code `f.set(this, rs.getString(iCol));` is not executed in the subclass context but in `Field` context, as the `Field.set` method is accessing the class member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `Field.setAccessible(true)` before calling `Field.set`.

Answer (score -1):

It is normal, an abstract class can't be constructed .
Then it is impossible to construct it.
When you write `public class MyTable extends DBTable`, the compiler executes the inherited methods.
Test without *super();* I think it may work.

Comment: Calling `super()` does not instanciate a `DBTable` object (because, as you said, it is abstract and cannot be instanciated), but rather execute the code of `DBTable()`. I need that to go through all fields of my sub-class: in this case, the `getClass()` method returns an object of class `MyTable`, not `DBTable` (which is what I want), which means it is executed in the `MyTable` context.
However, method `setFieldClass()` seems to be executed in the `DBTable` context, which causes the Exception as it does not have access to `protected` members of its sub-classes.
I still don't understand why...

Comment: Now I know: because the code is executed in class `Field` context (see my comment up).